# Sequelize associate multiple tables to 1 table with 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, associations

Is it possible to connect multiple tables to single table with 2 foreign keys?
My tables:

```
const Products = sequelize.define("Products", {name: sequelize.STRING});
const Categories = sequelize.define("Categories ", {name: sequelize.STRING});

const Translations = sequelize.define("Translations ", {name: sequelize.STRING});
```

I want to connect Translations table to Products and Categories with foreign keys

```
'object_id' (object_id = product_id or category_id) and 'object_type' ( object_type= 'products' or 'categories');
```

The mysql queries I aim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Translations t 
JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = t.object_id AND t.object_type = 'products'
```

AND

```
SELECT * 
FROM Translations t 
JOIN Categories c ON c.category_id = t.object_id AND t.object_type = 'categories'
```

Also after delete row in products or categories to cascade delete it from translations;

Comment: You are looking for this query. `SELECT * 
FROM Translations t 
LEFT JOIN Products p ON p.product_id = t.object_id AND t.object_type = 'products'
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON c.category_id = t.object_id AND t.object_type = 'categories'`

Comment: I am looking for a separated queries and associations, exactly what I mentioned above, but with Sequelize

Comment: If you wish to use composite foreign keys then Sequelize does not support them.